# Not able to pick random values in Java

Tags: java

I have written the code as follows:
The code which i have tried as follows:

```
@Test()
public void FilterMatching() throws Exception{

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileReader("C:\\FilterSection\\dropdown.properties"));
ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.shuffle(expectedDropDownItems);
List<String> randomFive = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   if (i < expectedDropDownItems.size()) {
       randomFive.add((String) expectedDropDownItems.get(i));
   }
}
Log.info("1. Verifying the Visualization drop down values are matching in both property file and UI");
String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray =  properties.getProperty("visualizationId").trim().split(",");

Random r = new Random();
for(int i=expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length;i>0;i--){
   int index = r.nextInt(i);
   String temp = expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i];
   expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i] = expectedDropDownItemsInArray[index];
   expectedDropDownItemsInArray[index] = temp;
}

for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]);
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

}

The Situation is

1. Go to Property file
2. Store the values for each drop down from the property file
3. Or Pick any 5 random values in each key pair value from the property file
4. come to the FE and verify that the values are present in the drop down one bye one (in the sense 1st get one set of values from property and check in the similar drop down once it done move the next)

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Where are you populating `expectedDropDownItems`? It seems to be an empty list.

Comment: And what's the point of `randomFive`? You're populating it and then ignoring it...

Comment: please help what the change i have to do.. I'm the beginner of Java. little time taking for understanding.. Give the order hoe to do it

Comment: Please any one help me

Comment: Why do you ask the same question over and over again?

Comment: Creating an array or ArrayList of object type X does not create the X objects, but only allocates the "reference" variables to address them.  (As opposed to creating an array of scalar values such as `int` where the values *are* "created" and initialized to zero.)  So you must write a loop to "populate" your ArrayList with the objects of that type before you can reference them.

Comment: Note that a common problem newbies have (especially when they try to learn programming outside of the classroom) is understanding the difference between an *object* and a *reference* (pointer in C).  The object is the thing, the reference is the address of the thing.  You need to understand this very basic distinction.